# Remove Missing Data in Pandas (Python 3, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is frustrating me to no end --

I have a data frame called FINAL that looks like this

```
Match Type     Suffix     
0              NaN        
1              NaN        
2              NaN        
3              Exact                  
4              Exact
```

I want to get rid of all the NAN data using this:

```
final.dropna()
```

and this

```
final['Suffix'].dropna()
```

neither of them work!  What am I missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those operations return copies. You can either reassign the variable:

```
final = final.dropna()
```

Or pass `inplace=True`:

```
final.dropna(inplace=True)
```